Mobius Algebra Identity
I am working through Exercise 3.95 in Stanley’s Enumerative Combinatorics, which states in the Mobius algebra of a finite lattice $L$, given $z\in L$,
We have
$$\sum_{t\in L} \mu(0,t)t= \left(\sum_{u\leq z}  \mu(0,u)u\right)\left(\sum_{v\wedge z = 0} \mu(0,v)v\right)$$
I am confused, since this identity seems to imply that, if we take $z=0$, we have
$$\sum_{t\in L} \mu(0,t)t = (0)\left(\sum_{v\in L} \mu(0,v)v\right)= \sum_{v\in L} \mu(0,v)0,$$
and thus by comparing coefficients of all nonzero $v$, that $\mu(0,v) = 0$ for all nonzero $v$, which I know is not true. I must be making a mistake in my reasoning somewhere. Does anyone have any thoughts on it?

According to the Errata for the book,

The stated identity is actually valid for the dual Möbius algebra, where one uses the join operation rather than the meet. The correct identity using the text definition of Möbius algebra is
$$ \sum_{t\in L}\mu(t,\hat1)t = \left(\sum_{u\geq z}\mu(u,\hat1)u\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{v\vee z=\hat1}\mu(v,\hat1)v\right). $$

